# Al ingresar una contraseña incorrecta, la vuelva a preguntar

Tags: c

Quiero lograr que en este código, al ser la contraseña incorrecta, la vuelva a preguntar.. ¿alguna ayuda?

```
#include <16f877a.h>
#use delay(clock=4M)
#define use_portb_kbd true
#include <lcd.c>
#include <kbd.c>

void main()
{
 char clave[6];
 char b[6];
 char l;
 char j;
 int h;
 int i;
 port_b_pullups(true); // utiliza la resistencia interna del puerto b
 lcd_init(); // limpia la pantalla del lcd
 kbd_init(); // limpia el teclado (keypad_phone)
 i=0;
 h=0;
 printf(lcd_putc, "WELCOME TO\n" "ENGINE CONTROL");
 delay_ms(1500);
 lcd_init();
 lcd_gotoxy(1,1);
 printf(lcd_putc, "CREATE NEW \nPASSWORD:"  );


while(i<6)
   {
      l=kbd_getc(); // leer o asignar valor tecla
        if(l!=0)
          {
          clave[i]=l;
            i=i+1;
         }
  }
    lcd_init();
     printf(lcd_putc, "PASSWORD \nCREATED !!!" );
     delay_ms(1000);
     lcd_init();
     printf(lcd_putc, "ENTER PASSWORD:" );

while(h<6)
 {
  j=kbd_getc(); // leer o asignar valor tecla}
  if(j!=0)
    {
       b[h]=j;
       h=h+1;
    }
 }

if (b[0]==clave[0])
  {
     if (b[1]==clave[1])
       {
        if (b[2]==clave[2])
        {
          if (b[3]==clave[3])
           {
               if (b[4]==clave[4])
                  {
                    if (b[5]==clave[5])
                       {
                          lcd_init();
                          printf(lcd_putc, "PASSWORD \nCORRECT !!!");
                          output_high(pin_c1);
                          delay_ms(1000);
                          lcd_init();
                          printf(lcd_putc, "WELCOME :)");                         
                          delay_ms(1000);
                       }
 else
  {
     lcd_init();
     printf(lcd_putc, "INCORRECT \nPASSWORD");
     output_high(pin_c0);
     delay_ms(500);
    }
           }
 else
  {
     lcd_init();
     printf(lcd_putc, "INCORRECT \nPASSWORD");
     output_high(pin_c0);
     delay_ms(500);
    }
           }
 else
  {
     lcd_init();
     printf(lcd_putc, "INCORRECT \nPASSWORD");
     output_high(pin_c0);
     delay_ms(500);
  }
        }
  else
  {
     lcd_init();
     printf(lcd_putc, "INCORRECT \nPASSWORD");
     output_high(pin_c0);
     delay_ms(500);
    }
     }
  else
         {
     lcd_init();
     printf(lcd_putc, "INCORRECT \nPASSWORD");
     output_high(pin_c0);
     delay_ms(500);
         }
  }

  else
  {
     lcd_init();
     printf(lcd_putc, "INCORRECT \nPASSWORD");
     output_high(pin_c0);
     delay_ms(500);
    }
   lcd_init(); 
    }
```

Comment: Un código bastante largo como para leermelo pero básicamente intenta hacer un Do While a la hora de corroborar la autenticidad de la contraseña.

Answer (score 0):

Lamentablemente, no he podido entender tu código ya que está muy desorganizado y tampoco tiene las tabulaciones necesarias entre líneas para facilitar la legibilidad. Recuerda que los compañeros que intentan ayudarte no tendrán el tiempo suficiente para leer todo tu código y depurarlo, por eso debes siempre de pegar un ejemplo de tu código en donde estás teniendo el problema. Un código no es solamente para uso personal, sino para uso de todos y la organización de tu código es pésima como mencioné anteriormente. Inclusive, hasta tú puedes confundirte en cualquier momento al tratar de interpretar alguna línea. Te aconsejo que trabajes organizado.

Te invito a que pases por la sección de [Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) del sitio y leas [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y también [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A lo mejor pueda ayudarte para futuras preguntas en el sitio.

Regresando a tu solicitud de ayuda con tu problema, no tengo una solución definitiva ya implementada en tu código, pero puedo ayudarte con una técnica que podría solucionar tu problema.

Puedes usar un `do-while`. Los ciclos `do-while` son una estructura de control cíclica, los cuales nos permiten ejecutar una o varias líneas de código de forma repetitiva sin necesidad de tener un valor inicial e incluso a veces sin siquiera conocer cuando se va a dar el valor final. Son similares a los ciclos `while`, sin embargo el ciclo `do-while` nos permite añadir cierta ventaja adicional y esta consiste que nos da la posibilidad de ejecutar primero el bloque de instrucciones antes de evaluar la condición necesaria, de este modo los ciclos `do-while`, son más efectivos para algunas situaciones especificas, por ejemplo para lo que deseas hacer que es solicitar la contraseña una y otra vez hasta que sea correcta.

**Cómo se usa un ciclo `do-while`?**

```
do
{
        ....
        ....
    Bloque de Instrucciones....
        ....
        ....
}
while(condición de finalización);
```

**Ejercicio de ejemplo**: Ingresar un número mayor que 1

```
//Declaración de variables
int liNumero;

//Entrada de datos
do{
printf("Ingrese un n%cmero mayor que 1: ", 163);
scanf("%d", &liNumero);

if (liNumero <= 1) // Validar número
    printf("\n\tError!, el n%cmero debe ser mayor que 1.\n\n", 163);

} while (liNumero <= 1); // Condición
```

Este `do-while` va a ejecutarse una y otra vez siempre y cuando el número sea menor o igual que 1. Si el número es mayor que 1, entonces el ciclo se detiene y sale del `do-while`.

Puedes tomar este ejemplo y aplicarlo a tus necesidades. Espero haberte ayudado o al menos guiado para que encuentres la solución a tu problema.

Comment: muchas gracias.

Comment: Estamos para ayudarte. Si te ha servido mi Respuesta y has solucionado tu problema, no olvides en votar la Respuesta y seleccionarla como Respuesta Elegida. Cualquier duda estamos aquí. Saludos.